# localStorage gets cleared when route changes on vue web app

Tags: vue.js, safari, vue-router

I am storing a token after login in localStorage and using it to make api requests. On safari I am facing an issue that once I login and redirect to the home page, after that If I go to any other route ex /user safari is clearing a token stored in local storage and thus I am getting logged out. It is a Vue web app and I am using the Vue router for navigation.
Can anyone please suggest something
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the same issue in some other browser or it is happening only in safari ?

Comment: Can you post more information , post the code so I'll see how your storing the token in local storage ....and have you tried another browser?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Facing issue only on safari, working on chrome, firefox, brave

Comment: @jibzy its basic localStorage setItem and getItem methods